# How do i make a white object non transparent in adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'am working on a game, and in that game I have a white paper plane.

My problem is, is that my white paper plane is not white but transparent, is there a way to make this white/non transparent. I did  some research but I could only find non transparent > transparent.

edit: The two white planes are not white but transparent, I can't fill them with live paint bucket because it doesn't recognize the white planes (because i already filled the grey spots with it)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the object actually has a fill color set to white? There is no transparent white in Illustrator, unless you count the art board color, which shows white bg for convenience, but is actually transparent.

Comment: Hi 2hTu2, so you created a white paper plane in illustrator. When you exported the image, did you export as a png with transparency? When   you brought the image into your game was the plane transparent or not showing at all? If the image is transparent then your white plane might not be 100% opacity or you have some coding issues. Or I would go with Joonas comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you draw this? If so based on the image your lines do not look like they join to make a complete shape. Only shapes can be filled.

The white planes need to be a complete shape/joined paths. You can then select the shape using the selection tool. Then use fill dropdown to add the colour, not the paint bucket.

Comment: Well I could use live paint bucket for the two grey spots, so there is no problem with incomplete shapes (also this plane is in reality a lot smaller so you don't notice that the lines do not make perfect corners)

Comment: the grey areas are completed by the over lapping white triangles, thats why you can use the paint bucket.

Comment: if that is the case, how can I fix this?

Comment: @2hTu2 When using the pen tool, just make sure the last line connects to the original point. You will see a little circle next to the pen tool indicating a completed path that will now be fillable but the paint bucket.

Comment: i did make sharp edges, but i still can't fill the transparent planes

Comment: i found the solution, i traced all the lines with the pen, now i can fill the planes. thanks for the answers.